# Refer to Ranorex repository elements dynamically

Tags: c#, ranorex

I have the following issue.

I'd like to refer to some repository elements dynamically.

For example, I have a button. Let's say it is a delete button.

It's name is constructed like this:
suppose I want to delete an element called "Joe"
In this case the delete button is called in Spy:

```
Joe.DeleteButton
```

In case of Bill, it is called

```
Bill.DeleteButton
```

If I want to implement a click on it I'd like to use a statement like this:

```
repo.Joe.DeleteButton.Cklick();
repo.Bill.DeleteButton.Cklick();
```

But the name is determined during runtime.

Can I set, construct this repo...  statement dynamically or is there a way to refer to it dynamically (during runtime)?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. You have a problem that you want to solve by introducing Joe and Bill as dynamic objects. But what is your problem? Maybe it can be solved in an even more elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

If Joe and Bill have identical type and located on some repo container you can find them like this

```
Ranorex.Adapter namesContainer = repo.NamesContainer.Self;
List<*Names_Type*> namesList = namesContainer.FindChildren<*Names_Type*>();
```

after that, each name can be clicked in that way

`namesList[1].DeleteButton.Click();`

Answer (score 0):

For me to give a complete answer, I would need to know the XPath of both the delete buttons.

For example, if Joe and Bill are both forms and they both contain the delete button, the XPath syntax of the repo items could be something like this:

Joe Delete button = `/form[@title='Joe']/button[@accessiblename='Delete']`

Bill Delete button = `/form[@title='Bill']/button[@accessiblename='Delete']`

If you only wan't to click the delete button, regardless of the form name, simply change the XPath syntax to this:

Any Delete button = `/form/button[@accessiblename='Delete']`

You could add @processname to ensure it is the delete button of your app, or use anything else unique to your app under test.

In your particular issue, the Ranorex Spy is your best friend.

If you wan't to know more about XPath, I recommened watching Ranorex screencasts (really worth your time):
[Ranorex Screen casts](http://www.ranorex.com/support/screencasts.html)

There is also valuable information about XPaths in the following article:
[Ranorex XPath tips and tricks](http://www.ranorex.com/blog/ranorexpath-tips-and-tricks/)

Hope this helps!